# TensorFlow Dense and ReLU layers causing Segmentation fault error

Tags: python, tensorflow, segmentation-fault

I'm creating a neural network using TensorFlow.
I have some helper functions in the help.py file:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

def read_mnist(folder_path="MNIST_data/"):
    return input_data.read_data_sets(folder_path, one_hot=True)

def build_training(y_labels, y_output, learning_rate=0.5):
    # Define loss function
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_labels, logits=y_output))
    #train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)
    train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(loss)

    # Calculate accuracy
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_output,1), tf.argmax(y_labels,1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    return train_step, accuracy

def train_test_model(mnist, x_input, y_labels, accuracy, train_step, steps=1000, batch=100):
    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(steps):
      input_batch, labels_batch = mnist.train.next_batch(batch)
      feed_dict = {x_input: input_batch, y_labels: labels_batch}

      if i%100 == 0:
        train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict=feed_dict)
        print("Step %d, training batch accuracy %g"%(i, train_accuracy))

      train_step.run(feed_dict=feed_dict)

    print("The end of training!")

    print("Test accuracy: %g"%accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x_input: mnist.test.images, y_labels: mnist.test.labels}))
```

Then I try to use it when training the network.
First I use very simple 1 output layer:

```
import help
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Read mnist data
mnist = help.read_mnist()

image_size = 28
labels_size = 10

# Input layer - flattened images
x_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, image_size*image_size])
y_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, labels_size])

# Layers:
# - Input
# - Output (Dense)

# Output dense layer
y_output = tf.layers.dense(inputs=x_input, units=labels_size)

# Define training
train_step, accuracy = help.build_training(y_labels, y_output)

# Run the training & test
help.train_test_model(mnist, x_input, y_labels, accuracy, train_step)
```

Then I add another ReLU layer:

```
# Hidden Layer
hidden = tf.layers.dense(inputs=x_input, units=hidden_size, activation=tf.nn.relu)

# Output dense layer
y_output = tf.layers.dense(inputs=hidden, units=labels_size)
```

I get Segmentation fault error both times.
I tried few things that I found online like reordering numpy and tensorflow import clauses, putting the help.py code in the same file as the network architecture and training process or increasing the memory for the docker image. Nothing worked.

Can someone help?

Comment: I don't see **hidden_size** defined anywhere.  Is this all your code?

Comment: there is hidden_size defined as 1024, sorry for not pasting it

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to the next version of TensorFlow, version 1.2. It fixed all the issues.